# Java и математика

Tags: java, c++, алгоритм

Есть ли книга по математике для программистов? Как применять знания математики в программах? Есть ли книга в которой математические формулы записывают программным языком допустим `java` или `c`++.

Comment: Так вам знания математики нужны или знания алгоритмов?

Comment: @IgorGolovin что  есть алгоритм?

Comment: Алгоритм - это последовательность действий, приводящая к решению конкретной задачи. Например, алгоритм сортировки.

Comment: это не просто последовательность действий. Это последовательность действий, понятных исполнителю. Это очень важно

Comment: То есть это действие в заранее продуманное мною да ?

Comment: нет. Если Вы пишете алгоритм для ребенка 3 лет, то ему нельзя сказать "а здесь возьми сферический интеграл" (я говорю о среднестатистическом ребенке). Но если это алгоритм для студента первого курса, то можно смело писать "сложи два числа" (хотя студенты бывают разные).

Comment: Попробуйте *Роберт Седжвик, Кевин Уэйн. "Алгоритмы на Java"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть прекрасный сайт [teachyourselfcs.com](https://teachyourselfcs.com/) в котором присутствует раздел [**Mathematics for Computer Science**](https://teachyourselfcs.com/#math).

Там доступны ссылки на видеолекции и книгу.